# Mounting afp shares as non-interactive user

Tags: raspbian, media-server, mount

I am trying to run a music streaming server (squeezebox) on my rPi running raspbian from a network volume mounted with the afp protocol. The disk lives on an Apple Time Capsule. (I have seen thread 8386 about mounting the disk using CIFS; my file names contain spaces, etc. so I don't know that they'll work over SMB.) The server runs as its own user (squeezeboxserver) with no shell (/bin/false). I created a mount point in /mnt, changed the ownership to this user, and added a line to /etc/fstab:

afpfs#afp://guest:guest@10.0.1.1/Public /mnt/Music fuse user=squeezeboxserver,group=fuse 0 0

as per the [afpfs-ng documentation](https://sites.google.com/site/alexthepuffin/home). At first the afpfs executable wasn't found; I created it as a bash script  following [this advice](http://sourceforge.net/p/afpfs-ng/discussion/623356/thread/c3dc2745/) from the afpfs-ng forum.But the afpfs daemon won't start for the user in question:

pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo mount -a

The afpfs daemon does not appear to be running for uid 108, let me start it for you

*** buffer overflow detected ***: mount_afp terminated

Trying to startup afpfsd: No such file or directory

I'm at a loss -- any ideas?

Comment: OP here. After a bunch of experimenting it turns out that the problem arises from trying to mount the Time Capsule disk with credentials for user with read-only access to the disk. If I use credentials for a user with read/write access I'm able to mount the disk successfully (even as a read-only volume on the Pi).

Answer (score 0):

Add the path environment variable to the afpfs bash script like this:

## !/bin/bash

export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/opt/vc/bin:/home/pi/.xbmc-current/xbmc-bin/bin

mount_afp $3 $4 $1 $2

mount_afp doesn't find the daemon.

Comment: have you read the comment on the question before answering?